# Eclipse doesn't place the classes in the bin folder anymore

Tags: java, eclipse

I was making a game for school, and it works all and stuff but now I have a big problem.
I wanted to add doors, and keys. I finished the door part and wanted to test it. It didn't work. It's not about the code, everything is fine. I saw that my classes were not build in the bin folder.

the bin folder of the program: 
http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/37/bf/37bf1527e7a2028bfaf9188e9571c465.png

The classes (in Eclipse):
http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/38/a0/38a0f0e0a3b376c40d7689bc0e6a23aa.png

Also as you can see, in eclipse there is a "!" on top of the project.

Now the problem is: How do I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Greetings Carolien.

EDIT:
I got everything fixed now thanks for helping (feeling really dumb now -_-) it was something with order and export (still dont know what but i clicked select all and suddenly everything was fixed)

Comment: Is there anything listed under the markers/problems views?

Comment: hmm yes, I found something, 

"Project 'aMAZEing' is missing required source folder: 'data' aMAZEing"

I think I know what it is but I deleted it before, I used it at first to hold the images and stuff, but now I moved everything to the res folder. I dont think I need the folder data somewhere but it can be true that I checked it somewhere for the build to runable jar or something

EDIT: http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/ae/50/ae50ec27a85d8975056cc8b59803cb13.png 

This is the java build path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason for moving everything to the res folder? You might need to move everything back into your src folder. Also you should check the box in the build path "Allow output folders for source folders".